# How can I populate attributes of a POJO by maps key and value

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Say I have a `Map<String,String>` and a POJO like below

```
class Model {
   String name;
   String value;
}
```

I need to populate the name and value of Model by key and value of EntrySet of Map. Apart from iterating over the Map and doing the same is there any API available that can convert this map to List or Array of populated Model.

Comment: What's wrong with iterating over the map and instantiating each object as you go.

Comment: You'll need to iterate over the EntrySet and copy the name and values into your new objects one at a time, and then store them in your list.

I assume you have a reason why you can't just use the Entry directly?

Comment: Well there no challenge as such. Just wanted to check if there is any library  available.

Answer (score 3):

You can always iterate over `EntrySet` but as far as an API is concerned, there is an *Apache*  `BeanUtils` available [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#populate(java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Map)), which you can use to convert `Map` to a `Class`.

Use it like below :-

```
Map<String,String> yourMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
yourMap.put("name", "Joan");
yourMap.put("value", "30");

Model model = new Model();

try {
    BeanUtils.populate(model, yourMap);
} 
catch (Throwable e) {
    //do something...
}
```

Comment: @user3386493 if the above worked for you you can choose this answer as the correct answer.